# Implementing a special array using Constructor

Tags: c++11

Implementing a special array using constructor.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int length(const int *s){
  int L;
  for(L=0; s[L] != '\0'; L++){};
  return L;
}
void scopy(int destination[], const int source[], int dstart=0)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0; source[i] != '\0'; i++)
    destination[dstart+i]=source[i];
  destination[dstart+i]=source[i];    // copy the '\0' itself
}
class eArray
{
        int *ptr;
        void * operator new(unsigned int sz);
        public:
        eArray()
        {
            ptr=NULL;
        }
        int size()const {cout<<"Hi";return length(ptr);}
        int& operator[](int i) const {return ptr[i];}

        eArray(const eArray &rhs)
        {
            ptr = new int[length(rhs.ptr)+1];
            scopy(ptr,rhs.ptr);
        }
        eArray& operator=(const int* rhs)
        {
            delete [] ptr;
            ptr = new int[length(rhs)+1];
            scopy(ptr,rhs);
            return *this;
        }
        eArray& operator=(const eArray &rhs)
        {
            delete [] ptr;
            ptr = new int[length(rhs.ptr)+1];
            scopy(ptr,rhs.ptr);
            return *this;
        }
        void push_back(int v)
        {
            cout<<"Hi2";
            int *a=new int[length(ptr)+2];
            scopy(a,ptr);
            a[length(ptr)]=v;
            a[length(ptr)+1]='\0';
            delete[] ptr;
            ptr=new int[length(a)+1];
            scopy(ptr,a);
        }
};
```

Runtime error occurs on giving input. I think its wrong in the length() function. Please help.When I give a number as input(say 2)then it prints Hi2 in push_back function and it terminates.

Comment: Have you tried running in debug mode? That would usually tell you the operation that it fails at

Comment: what is your main function?

Answer (score 0):

`eArray()` default constructor initializes `ptr` to `NULL`. But then almost every operation assumes a non-null `ptr`; `push_back` among them. They all call `length(ptr)`, and `length` always dereferences the pointer, never checks it for null.

As written, the only way to produce an `eArray e` instance for which `e.ptr != NULL` is via  `operator=(const int*)`, by assigning a raw `int*` pointer to it.